# Adding Geomedia WebMap WFS to ArcGIS Online maps

Tags: arcgis-online, wfs, getfeature, geomedia

I'm having troubles adding a WFS layer, published through Geomedia WebMap, to an ArcGIS Online map. It recognizes the URL and the layer of the features, but doesn't show any features in the map (or in the attribute table) and doesn't recognize correctly the available fields (it only shows the first one).

In QGIS, I am able to add the data as a WFS data source with no problem.

Below I provide the results of a query to the service returning only one feature:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<gmgml:FeatureCollection numberOfFeatures="1" xmlns="http://www.intergraph.com/geomedia/gml" xmlns:gmgml="http://www.intergraph.com/geomedia/gml" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.intergraph.com/geomedia/gml http://myorganizationserver/Cadastro-WFS/service.svc/get?request=DescribeFeatureType&amp;version=1.1.0&amp;TypeName=VETROCOCOLECTORMUN&amp;OutputFormat=text/xml;subtype=gml/3.1.1&amp;service=wfs">
 <gml:boundedBy>
 <gml:Envelope srsName="EPSG:3857">
 <gml:lowerCorner>-1025452.67332012 4677949.3337205</gml:lowerCorner>
 <gml:upperCorner>-1025324.26923474 4677964.86696932</gml:upperCorner>
 </gml:Envelope>
 </gml:boundedBy>
 <gml:featureMember>
 <gmgml:VETROCOCOLECTORMUN gml:id="VETROCOCOLECTORMUN.132">
 <gmgml:IPID>1022398</gmgml:IPID>
 <gmgml:DATA_DE_ACTUALIZACAO>2016-03-16</gmgml:DATA_DE_ACTUALIZACAO>
 <gmgml:GEOMETRY>
 <gml:LineString srsName="EPSG:3857">
 <gml:posList srsDimension="2">-1025452.67332012 4677949.3337205 -1025324.26923474 4677964.86696932 </gml:posList>
 </gml:LineString>
 </gmgml:GEOMETRY>
 </gmgml:VETROCOCOLECTORMUN>
 </gml:featureMember>
</gmgml:FeatureCollection>
```

I've noticed two strange things that I don't know if they can be the origin of the problem:

- There is a *gmgml* prefix in several tags (it seems to be a prefix
  specific of Geomedia datasources, but does this draw the data
  invalid, since it is correctly shown in QGIS?)
- The *xmlns* and *xmlns:gmgml* url points to an invalid web address (It
  seems an outdated url, but I couldn't find the current valid url for
  this documentation)

Comment: The urls in the XML file don't need to resolve for a service to be valid.    The namespace prefix, shouldn't be a problem either.

Comment: is the GetFeature result what you get in QGIS, a direct request, or in ArcGIS?    Can you sniff out what actual GetFeature  request is made by ArcGIS?

Comment: @nmtoken: the presented resulting code was obtained by a direct request. Checking the requests made by ArcGIS Online Map Viewer I see that it gets a FeatureCollection identical to what I get by direct request, although it uses a post method instead to make the call to the service